# Searching in Nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am searching for the following string in a nvarchar(max) column

```
<script src="http://d1.openx.org/ajs.php?zoneid=75288&amp;source
```

However when I use CharIndex and try to find, I get 0

How can I search for that string? I am using SQL 2008

Comment: Please post the CHARINDEX query you're using. I tested this and it appears to work fine.

Comment: it seems there is a problem in the equals to (=). When I search only <script src, I get a valid charindex, but as soon as I do <script src=  i get 0. Can you show the query you used to test this string.

Comment: It would be better if you showed your non-functional query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me. Are you sure you have the parameters in the right order?

```
create table #t
(test nvarchar(max))


insert #t 
select 'abcdefghijklmnop<script src="http://d1.openx.org/ajs.php?zoneid=75288&amp;source12345'



select charindex('<script src="http://d1.openx.org/ajs.php?zoneid=75288&amp;source',test,0)
from #t
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add that if this is database cleanup, you can use REPLACE to change things around easily.

you might check that your data doesn't have an < instead of <